# Trigger IMPORTRANGE using query not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use Query and IMPORTRANGE to get data from another google sheet when a checkbox in the column is TRUE. But I'm just getting an error..

Found this solution:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("G-Sheet URL", "TAB & range"), "where Col15=TRUE", 1)
```

My code:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o/edit#gid=0", "Spelbricka!C6:C12"), "where Col6=TRUE", 1)
```

It just gives me error.

Anyone?

Thanks on behalf / R

[image]

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19d_yMCKuLVJB36OQorpUp0VrTYWt24WjFeBy7tVl5Ic/edit#gid=0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a range **if** one of your cells in that sheet is set to true, you will be wanting to set everything with an [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) condition and wrap the [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) with an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) function. `ARRAYFORMULA` will let you display an array of values in differnt rows and columns rather than a single one avoiding therefore errors (as `IF` itself would just accept returning a single value), making your non-array function into an array function.

Moreover, with this you can also choose to return another `IMPORTRANGE` is the checkbox is unmarked. In the following example I'm importing a range if the cell `B1` checkbox is ticked.

```
=(IF(B1=True,ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("SHEETURL","Sheet1!C6:C12")),""))
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Mateo Randwolf

I tested your example: 

=(IF(C5=True,ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("19d_yMCKuLVJB36OQorpUp0VrTYWt24WjFeBy7tVl5Ic","Spelbrickor!C8:C10")),""))

But I'm getting a Error in formula interpretation.. What can it be?

Comment: Hi ! I think it is because you are not passing your Spreadsheet URL in ```IMPORTRANGE``` and instead you are passing your sheet ID ```19d_yMCKuLVJB36OQorpUp0VrTYWt24WjFeBy7tVl5Ic```. Try changing it to ```https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o/edit#gid=0``` (or whatever your Spreadsheet URL is)

Comment: It's the same with the full url..
`=(IF(C5=True,ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19d_yMCKuLVJB36OQorpUp0VrTYWt24WjFeBy7tVl5Ic/edit#gid=0","Spelbrickor!C8:C10")),""))`

Comment: Hi ! Could you grant me edit level access to find out where the issue might be coming from ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Yes, change the commas in the formula ```,``` to semi colons ```;```. It would be like this ```IF(C5=True;ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19d_yMCKuLVJB36OQorpUp0VrTYWt24WjFeBy7tVl5Ic/edit#gid=0";"Spelbrickor!C8:C10"));"")```. Also note that if you are using this in ```C7``` you cannot try to import the same range as the cell you are using the formula in.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This helped me a lot. I'm getting the data from another sheet document. So that's why I use the same cells!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider [accpeting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvoting my answer if it helped you solve your issue. :D

Answer (score 1):

first run this in any cell and allow access:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!A6")
```

then try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!A6:E12"); "select Col3 where Col6=TRUE"; 0)
```

notice the range A6:E12 where we return column C only if column E equals TRUE

---

### UPDATE:

use in C6:

```
=IF(
 IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A6; 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!A:A"); 0); 3))=TRUE; 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A6; 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!A:A"); 0); 3)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A6; 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ztQla9sOO7xkQdSAMOKHcas81H4jVbYjg9tVi9w1u0o"; 
 "Spelbricka!A:A"); 0)+6; 3)); )
```

[image]

- then select C6
- copy it with <kbd>`CTRL`</kbd> + <kbd>`C`</kbd>
- and paste with <kbd>`CTRL`</kbd> + <kbd>`V`</kbd> into C15, C24, etc.